# gcc couldn't locate slab.h in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, gcc, programming, c

Please correct me if I'm missing something here. Thanks for your inputs.

Header included in code: `#include <linux/slab.h>`

Code snippet from my file that's asking for memory allocation using "kmalloc()":

```
/*
 * Initialize memory.
 */
 char* fs_ptr;
 fs_ptr = kmalloc((sizeof(char) * 20), GFP_USER);

 if (!fs_ptr) 
       printf("Error allocating space in memory.\n");
 }
```

Compile error:

```
$ make
gcc -g -Wall `pkg-config fuse --cflags` -c fs.c
fs.c:43:24: fatal error: linux/slab.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Ubuntu version Info.:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-33-generic #48~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 24 16:28:06 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Location of header file, searching via 'locate':

```
$ locate slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-31-generic/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-32-generic/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33-generic/include/linux/slab.h
```

Comment: You need to pass the `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-33/include/` option to GCC. You may want to learn about Autotools or CMake, that will do the work for you.

Comment: @smaven, could you please update? so  it to be answered by Andrea or you anyway you had solved it.